# GridView NullReferenceException Error in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am accessing a TextField within a GridView. It shouldn't pick the updated text, instead, it takes the original text only. I am using two GridViews within the same page in different tabs. Will that make them affect each other?

But the GridView is giving me an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in OnlineExamDesign.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRowTeam")
            {
                DomainTeam updateObj = new DomainTeam();
                int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                string name = ((TextBox)domainGrid.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtchangeTeamName")).Text;
                updateObj.actionTeam(index,name,"TeamUpdate");
                teamGrid.EditIndex = -1;
                getTeamGridData();
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Anjan, Please share whole code this block of code is not sufficient to understand the problem.

Comment: Chances are there is no TextBox named `txtchangeTeamName`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;
 TextBox TextBox1 = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox; 

  string myString = TextBox1.Text; //Access TextBox1 here.
```